# Dynamic/Encrypted Key in @SerializeName in android

Tags: android, parsing, security

As security is a major concern for mobile engineers, any `release apk` can be easily decompiled and inspected the important keys or data, etc... when using `Proguard`, the string literals are there as it is and can be extracted. There are ways to overcome this problem like using cryptography or native codes. My question is, When using `gson` to parse network response, is there anyway to use dynamic key in `@SerializeName("header")`, I know this will give error `An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant` when using key dynamically. OR any other way to parse network response where **object keys should not exposed when reverse engineered the app.**

```
data class SomeResponse(
    @SerializedName("header") <- //this will give compile-time error when using dynamic key.
    val header: String)
```

**P.S.** Please do not answer related to **DexGuard** or **Manual JSON parsing**.

Comment: is this really such a big security risk i wonder ? in theory, wouldn't someone be able to view your network requests and responses anyway if they wanted to ?

Comment: We want to hide the keys that the attacker couldn't even get the hint of network request/response

Comment: i doubt this is something you'll ever be able to achieve from the app, because any mapping logic will also be quite obvious and logical to someone who decompiles